# call function whenever new element added inside v-for tr td tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to call a function evenever `v-for` has new element added. IN my case the element is `choosen_products`, so whenever I have new element inside v-for I want to call `CalculateSubtotal(i)`, the `choosen_products` origionally has 0 elements but it will cimulative wheneve I press add button (no inside this scrop) however, even I try `@change`, nothing has been call yet.

```
    <tr v-for="p, i in choosen_products" @change="CalculateSubtotal(i)">
    
    <td> {{ p.p_fullname }} </td>
    <td> {{ p.p_code }} </td>
    <td> {{ p.p_category }} </td>
    <td> {{ p.p_cost }} </td>
    <td> {{ p.p_margin }} </td>
    
    <td :ref="'add_all_sell'+i" :id="'add_all_sell'+i" th:onload="CalculateSubtotal(i)"> 
{{ p.p_sell }} 
</td>
</tr>
```

Instead of `@change`, how to let the program recognize `tr` or `td` has new elment, call function?

Comment: Make `subtotal` a computed based on `chosen_products`. Computed = Derived state. Whenever `chosen_products` changes the `subtotal` automatically updates, because it's a reducer function.

Comment: how to computed in chosen_products? @computed?

Answer (score 0):

The tag `<tr>` has no `onchange` event.

You will need an array length `watcher` to watch your array changes.

```
watch(() => choosen_products.length, (choosen_products) => {
  console.log(choosen_products.length)
})
```

### Playground

```js
const { createApp, ref, watch } = Vue

const App = {
  setup() {
    const choosen_products = ref([])
    const CalculateSubtotal = () => { console.log(choosen_products.value.length) }

    watch(() => choosen_products.value.length, (choosen_products) => {
      CalculateSubtotal();
    })
    return { choosen_products, CalculateSubtotal  }
  }
}

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
li.active { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  {{choosen_products}}&nbsp;
  <button @click="choosen_products.push(choosen_products.length)">+1</button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: I try this but `choose_products` still bonds with props in component, when I use this I cannot use prop variable transfer from component